# How to read data from nested JSON structure in protractor

Tags: json, node.js, protractor

Below is my code and I want to extract data under "specs" part like description, status etc. however I'm getting undefined when I capture the data and print it in the console. I have tried

```
let web = JSON.parse(jsondata);
let TestSuite = web["suite1"]["description"]
```

and this is providing data in console however, when I use this,

```
let id = web["suite1"]["specs"]["id"]
```

its gives undefined. Please help!

> ```
> {
> "suite1": {
>     "id": "suite1",
>     "description": "Login",
>     "fullName": "Login",
>     "failedExpectations": [],
>     "status": "finished",
>     "specs": [
>         {
>             "id": "spec0",
>             "description": "Should able to login into the Distribution management Webpage",
>             "fullName": "Login Should able to login into the Distribution management Webpage",
>             "failedExpectations": [
>                 {
>                     "matcherName": "",
>                     "message": "",
>                     "stack": "",
>                     "passed": false,
>                     "expected": "",
>                     "actual": ""
>                 }
>             ],
>             "passedExpectations": [],
>             "pendingReason": "",
>             "started": "2018-09-06T06:57:42.740Z",
>             "status": "failed",
>             "duration": "7 secs",
>             "stopped": "2018-09-06T06:57:49.255Z",
>             "browserLogs": []
>         }
>     ]
> } }
> ```

Comment: Would you please provide the code you have tried?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed    let jsondata = fs.readFileSync('C:\\AutomationTestResults.json');
      let web = JSON.parse(jsondata);
      let TestSuite = web["suite1"]["description"] this gives me "login" in console, however, when i use let id = web["suite1"]["specs"]["id"], i get "undefined" in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`specs` contains an array of objects. First, you need to get the object from the array and then get a value of the object.

Try this:

```
let id = web["suite1"]["specs"][0]["id"]
```

**OR**

```
let id = web.suite1.specs[0].id
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: @Shruti Which answer gave you the solution?

Comment: I'm sorry, all the answers are same and are solutions. but i tried yours first. Thank you.

Comment: I have one question here. here "failedExpectations": is displaying information because the test case got failed. however, if this testcase passes and now "failedExpectations": [] displays. then how we incorporate here. Can we place a check here whether its displaying or not?

Comment: `failedExpectations` also contains an array. First, you can get the array from `failedExpectations` and then get count the array. For success result `failedExpectations` array count will be 0 and other might you got the count.

Comment: Ok, i will try it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json)).suite1.specs[0].id
```

Comment: it dint work, i tried like this:                                                                                      let web = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsondata)).suite1.specs

Comment: Shruti, Can you check the type of json using typeof operator? Is this an object or a string.

Comment: I am trying the same and its giving me the result

Comment: Also did you stringified and then parsed?

Comment: Sorry i dint stringfy, but i dont know how to do.. can you please explain me?

Comment: specs is an array now 
do this:
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json)).suite1.specs[0].something

Comment: Let me know if you got it - JSON.parse() takes a JSON string and transforms it into a JavaScript object. JSON.stringify() takes a JavaScript object and transforms it into a JSON string.

Comment: Hey Shruti, I saw you changed the acceptance of the answer, was the answer not worth your explanation?

Comment: Actually, all the answers are correct solution for me. however, since i tried other answer first, i marked it as answer. Thank you for your help as well. I cant mark it but i really appreciate your help and the solution.

Comment: Ok, please mark it if you find the answer is worth, if not you can leave it.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `["suite1"]["specs"]`, you select array. You need an index, which is the `0`-th one in this case.

You can check that by typing `Object.prototype.toString.call( data["suite1"]["specs"])`.

You can try with:

```
data["suite1"]["specs"][0]["id"]
```

Or use the object property notation

```
data["suite1"]["specs"][0].id
```